# Jquery select previous element with class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 elements:

```
<div class='first'>First</div>
<div class='second'>Second</div>
<div class='target'>Target</div>
```

on click on `target` `div` I test `.prev()` function in my js

```
$(document).on('click','.target',function(){
    console.log($(this).prev().html());
    console.log($(this).prev('.first').html());
});
```

Output is like: 'Second undefined', but should be like: 'second first' if I understand right the parameter of .prev() usage.
How can I get first previous element with certain class then?
Here is fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/0fzgzce5/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From jQuery docs,

[.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)

> Description: Get the immediately preceding sibling of each element in
>   the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.
>
> To select all preceding sibling elements, rather than just the
>   preceding adjacent sibling, use the .prevAll() method.

http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/

So you should use `console.log($(this).prevAll('.first').html());`

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `sibling()` which will return the element with specific class and at same level as calling elment. But make sure that there is no same div after `target`

```
$(document).on('click','.target',function(){
    console.log($(this).siblings('.second').html());
    console.log($(this).siblings('.first').html());
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0fzgzce5/4/)**

OR you can use `prevAll()`

```
$(document).on('click','.target',function(){
        console.log($(this).prevAll('.second').html());
        console.log($(this).prevAll('.first').html());
    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0fzgzce5/6/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use `prevAll()` instead of `prev()`

```js
$(document).on('click', '.target', function() {
  alert($(this).prevAll('.second').html());
  alert($(this).prevAll('.first').html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='first'>First</div>
<div class='second'>Second</div>
<div class='target'>Target</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use also `$("div:eq(3)")` to get the exact element. Best example is `$("ul li:eq(3)")`

Answer (score 0):

In your second `console.log()`, yous `this` is still `.target` and it does not have `.first` class so it is saying `undefined`.

To get the first dive, do:

```
console.log($(this).prev().prev().html());
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery `.prev()` always get immediate preceding sibling.

if you pass a selector as parameter it will filter the preceding element to match with, if it did not match it will return undefined, in your case this is happening

```
$('.target').prev().html()
```

is same as

```
$('.target').prev('.second').html();
```

which will return "Second"

If you pass any selector other than '.second' it alway return  undefined so, your case

```
$('.target').prev('.first').html();
```

is as exprected, returning undefined because '.first' is not matching with preceding element selector.

**Update:**
if you want to get First the use

```
$('.target').prev().prev().html();
```